# android wakelock not released after getActiveNetworkInfo

Tags: android, wakelock

I want to automatically check for an internet connection every x minutes and send data to a server. However, the following (minimal) code gives a warning in Eclipse, saying that the release() call is not always reached.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
wl.acquire();

// check active network
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
// start a service that uploads data
wl.release();
```

I don't see how wl.release() could possibly not be called so is that a bug in Eclipse or what am I missing? I definitely don't want my app to cause a wake lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't see how wl.release() could possibly not be called

Well, if nothing else, you are not handling any exceptions. If something between `acquire()` and `release()` raises a `RuntimeException`, you will crash and leak the `WakeLock`. Use this:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
wl.acquire();

try {
  // check active network
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  // start a service that uploads data
}
finally {
  wl.release();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Odd, nevertheless, no exception should be thrown by cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()

Comment: @user2633688: First, not all runtime exceptions are documented. Second, I'm presuming that your `// start a service that uploads data` comment implies the existence of additional code, and that could have runtime exceptions.

Comment: I only put the comment to signal that I intend to do something useful with that bit of code but the warning shows up with exactly that code. Maybe it is an undocumented exception then.