# Must every WakeLock.release() call always be reached? android lint warning

Tags: android, android-wake-lock, android-lint

Android lint warns on the following with [Wakelock]:

```
public static void acquire(Context ctx, long timeout) {
    if (wakeLock != null) {
        wakeLock.release();
    }

    PowerManager powerManager
        = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                    PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                    PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, 
                    Common.TAG);
    wakeLock.setReferenceCounted(false);

    if ( timeout <= 0 ) {
        wakeLock.acquire();
    } else {
        wakeLock.acquire(timeout);
    }
}

public static synchronized void release() {
    if ( wakeLock != null ) {
        if ( wakeLock.isHeld() ) {
            wakeLock.release(); 
        }
        wakeLock = null;
    }
}
```

It gives the warning for the first occurrence

> [lint] [...]/WakeLocker.java: Warning: The release() call is not always reached [Wakelock]

Yet, it does not really *need* to be released every time, as there is a timeout.

The default solution of wrapping this in a `try-catch`-block, as for example in [android-wakelock-not-released-after-getactivenetworkinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128155/android-wakelock-not-released-after-getactivenetworkinfo), or in [@rainash's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31248012/1587329), do not address the problems that led to using this approach, namely [**that the device can go back to sleep**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864712/android-alarmmanager-not-waking-phone-up).

How is this fixed? Or should it be ignored?

Comment: `What to do?` You dont have to do anything its a warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed this seems to be a long forgotten problem. In fact this bug was reported to google already back in 2013 [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43212), but seems to still be there.

As one commenter states:

The following code get the warning:

```
try {
    wakeLock.acquire();
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
} finally {
    wakeLock.release();
}
```

Results in:

> The release() call is not always reached (via exceptional flow)

However, if you throw the Exception in a method, no warning is reported:

```
private void makeMistake() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception();
    ...
    try {
        wakeLock.acquire();
        makeMistake();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    ...
    } finally {
        wakeLock.release();
    }
}
```

To disable this warning, rather do it in your apps `build.gradle` file, for easy access, rather than inline as suggested by @user.

```
...
lintOptions {
        disable 'Wakelock'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use try-catch block wrap task you execute when device awake

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    final WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
    wakeLock.acquire();
            try {
                do something
            } finally {
                wakeLock.release();
            }
    });
```

Comment: The solution above is for when the device gets an alarm, but does not always react, because the timeout passes too fast, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864712/android-alarmmanager-not-waking-phone-up.

Comment: @user1587329 I don't know what your comment talking about, I met the warning before, if the task you excuted throws an exception when you wake up the device,.release() is not always reached

Comment: to summarize the link: sometimes you want a small class that **only** acquires a wakelock, because otherwise your device can go to sleep while the class doing the handling is loaded. I had this problem. Can you propose a solution that deals with that (major) and answers this lint-question (minor)?

Comment: upvoted for effort ;-) (and yes, this comment is not a real comment)

Comment: Can we `release` wakelock in a separate function?  Or does it have to be at the same callsite as `acquire`?

Answer (score 1):

As @tyczj hinted:

> [[Lint] also flags issues that may or may not be a problem depending on the context.](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings)

So think about the warning, and

> [If you've manually verified that an issue is not a problem, you may
>   want to mark the issue as verified such that lint does not keep
>   pointing it out.](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings)

To remove the warning in this case, use

```
@SuppressLint("Wakelock")
public static void acquire(Context ctx, long timeout) {
```

with

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
```